# Site name in SharePoint cascading dropdown functionality

Tags: sharepoint-online, cascading-dropdown

I am a SP Admin and new to coding. From the below script, i am not sure what should i keep as my site name. I am placing that script in content editor web part in the site https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection. According to this site, what should be my url from the below script be?

i tried to use cdn links [SP Services](http://Https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js), but the script is not loading, it says the script is not safe.

```
<script src="https://site name/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://sitename/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function ()  
{  
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
    {  
        relationshipList: "Employee",  
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Company",  
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  
        parentColumn: "Company",  
        childColumn: "Employee",  
        debug: true  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following link:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.6.2/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.6.2/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()  
    {  
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
        {  
            relationshipList: "Employee",  
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Company",  
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  
            parentColumn: "Company",  
            childColumn: "Employee",  
            debug: true  
         }); 
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are prefixing src url with `https://` then it needs to be the full absolute url (https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection), if you want to use a server-relative url in case your server name changes, then do not use the `https://` protocol prefix.

For example: `<script src="/sites/sitecollection/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: when i tried to access the url : https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/jquery.min.js it says 404 not found,

Comment: where did you upload your jquery source?  Did you put in a scripts folder or site assets library?  Make sure you have the full path to wherever you stored your javascript files.

Comment: If your copy of the jquery libraries are in the root of your SiteAssets library, I updated the example in my answer to reflect that.  If you have the library files in a subfolder or in a different library, make sure to include that in your path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see 'folder name' part in URL provided by you.

Follow next steps to upload JS files on your site in order to be able to use these scripts:

- Visit your site - https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection
- Click on Site contents > Site Assets
- Upload JS files to Site Assets folder(or any other document library)
- Open web page(or list form) where you want to use scripts
- Add new Script Editor Web Part(or Content Editor Web Part)
- Add your code

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/sitecollection/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/sitecollection/SiteAssets//jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
      $(document).ready(function ()  
      {  
          $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
          {  
              relationshipList: "Employee",  
              relationshipListParentColumn: "Company",  
              relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  
              parentColumn: "Company",  
              childColumn: "Employee",  
              debug: true  
           }); 
      });  
  </script>
  ```